# What are the alternatives for C++11 chrono?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, ctime

I am running my below code which checks whether `data_timestamp` is more than two weeks old or not. If it is more than two weeks old, then print `hello` otherwise prints `world`.

I am a Java developer, recently started working with C++. Learned few things over internet so I am using it here in this program. I didn't realize that not all code can be run using C++11 feature.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000; 

    const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = std::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    auto millis = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "<< millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) { 
        std::cout << "Hello"; 
    } else { 
        std::cout << "World"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Currently above code uses C++11 feature but the actual code in which I am using the above code logic of two weeks old timestamp doesn't support C++11 so I am looking for various alternative.

What else I can use here which doesn't require C++11 portability here? Can I use `<ctime>` or `Boost.Chrono` here?

Any simple example which does the same thing as above code and not uses C++11 features will be of great help.

**Update:-**

Below is the code I am trying -

```
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000; 

    const auto now = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto twoWeeks = boost::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    auto lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    auto millis = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "<< millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) { 
        std::cout << "Hello"; 
    } else { 
        std::cout << "World"; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As I was compiling the code using `make install -j4` below is the exception I am getting back -

```
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: ânowâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: âtwoWeeksâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: âlastTwoWeeksâ does not name a type
warning: âautoâ changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]
error: âmillisâ does not name a type
error: âmillisâ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: `boost::chrono` is certainly a very good alternative...

Comment: Of course you can use boost.chrono as C++11 chrono is based on it

Comment: ... and replace the `auto` declarations with the concrete `boost::chrono` datatypes then.

Comment: @quantdev Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide a simple example using `boot::chrono` which does the same thing?

Comment: @user2809564: As they said, change all `auto` to explicit types, and change all `std::chrono::` to `boost::chrono::` and `include <boost/chrono.hpp>`

Comment: @user2809564 I warned you about `auto` ca. 30 minutes prior you applied your edit. Do you read what we're saying?!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would advise `boost::chrono` since the C++11 specifications is largely based on `boost::date_time` (reading of proposals such as [this one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2661.htm) reveals how much boost was used as a base for `std::chrono`). As commented by Howard Hinnant, `boost::chrono` was then copied from `std::chrono`

It will also make things easier for you as soon as you will get a C++11 compiler available (easy to port to `std::`)

---

**A simple example :**

```
#include <boost/chrono/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    uint64_t data_timestamp = 1406066507000;

    const boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point now = boost::chrono::system_clock::now();
    boost::chrono::hours twoWeeks = boost::chrono::hours(24 * 14);
    boost::chrono::system_clock::time_point lastTwoWeeks = now - twoWeeks;

    boost::int_least64_t millis = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(lastTwoWeeks.time_since_epoch()).count();

    std::cout << "Time stamp in milliseconds since UNIX epoch start: "<< millis << std::endl;

    if (data_timestamp < millis) {
        std::cout << "Hello";
    } else {
        std::cout << "World";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion. I didn't realize c++11 chrono is quite similar to boost::chrono. Also, do you see any issues in comparing uint64_t with auto for timestamp comparison? data_timestamp has to be in uint64_t as that's what the old code is using as of now.

Comment: If `millis` can be negative, yes you'll have an issue. You might want to check that before doing the comparison.

Comment: Sure, thanks for extra tip. I tried compiling the code but somehow it is giving me compilation exception. I have updated the question with the compilation issues. Can you think of what went wrong?

Comment: `auto` type deduction is a c++11 feature, remove `auto` and use explicit types instead (edited, but I didnt try it)

Comment: For the record, `std::chrono` evolved from `boost::date_time`, and `boost::chrono` was copied from `std::chrono`. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks for the note ~ added in the post (feel free to edit)